# How to deal with metadata in a Many-To-Many relationship with Spring Data JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I have a project, where `bot_user`s play in `game_table`s. So I have a join table. I also store the `buy_in` (points available to the player at the table) in that join table. My SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE bot_users (
    user_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    free_points bigint CHECK (free_points >= 0),
    frozen_points bigint CHECK (frozen_points >= 0)
);

CREATE TABLE game_tables (
    channel_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    owner bigint REFERENCES bot_users(user_id),
    in_game boolean NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE game_tables_participants (
    game_table_id bigint REFERENCES game_tables(channel_id),
    participant_id bigint REFERENCES bot_users(user_id),
    buy_in bigint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (game_table_id, participant_id)
);
```

My question now is: how do I represent that `buy_in` metadata in entities in Java? If `buy_in` didn't exist, I would simply have a `ParticipantRef` of which I would have a `Set` in the `GameTable` entity, and then have methods that work on IDs there. But I want to have `buy_in` available in the code too, so should I create a `ParticipantRef`-like entity that contains the `buy_in`? If yes, then how would persisting it work?

Comment: Normally i split the many to many relationship in 2 of one to many like this post: https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed solution is pretty much the way to do this. Instead of having a `ParticipantRef` with just the `userId` of the `BotUsers` it also gets a `buyIn` attribute.

Since you have an object references from `GameTable` via a `Set` to the `ParticipantRef` it will be considered part of the GameTable-Aggregate and get persisted whenever you persist a `GameTable` instance.